# How can I create age band from different rows in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I have a table like this

```
rateId  gender  Age
HV1     M       0
HV1     M      12
HV1     M      50
HV1     F      0
HV1     F      20
HV1     F      50
```

I want to create an age band for all rateId per gender. When there is no upper age anymore, it can be 100.
So my result has to be:

```
rateId  gender  AgeLow  AgeHigh
HV1     M       0       12
HV1     M       12      50
HV1     M       50      100
HV1     F       0       20
HV1     F       20      50
HV1     F       50      100
```

I think it could be possible with a partition by or something like that, but I don't find how to use it.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using (mysql, sql server, oracle, postgres, etc..)? How this is solved will depend heavily on that.

Comment: It is in the title sql oracle

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try to use `LEAD` window function.

```
SELECT  t1.rateId, 
        t1.gender,  
        t1.Age AgeLow,
       LEAD(t1.Age,1,100) over(partition by t1.rateId,t1.gender order by t1.Age) AgeHigh
FROM T t1
```

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0c00a/3)**